# Closed form of the series

Tags: sequences-and-series, modular-arithmetic

I want to evaluate 
$\sum_{i=1}^{n} (x+i)^4$
So what i did is, after expanding it i reduce it to following form

$ x^{4} * n + 4 x^{3} * \sum_{i=1}^{n}i + 6x^2\sum_{i=1}^{n}i^{2} + 4x*\sum_{i=1}^{n}i^{3} + \sum_{i=1}^{n}i^4$

After doing this problem reduced to find $\sum_{i=1}^n i^a$ for $1\le a\le4$
.

This can be easily solved if
 $\sum_{i=1}^{n}i^4 = (n*(n+1)*(2n+1)*(3n^2 +3*n-1))/30 $
 can be computed mod M ( M is not prime).

I know 30 = 6*5, so 6 will get canceled by n or (n+1) or (2n+1). Now for 5 there are 4 cases

```
1) n%5==1 then 3n^2+3n-1 is divisible by 5 
2) n%5 = 2 then (2n+1) will help to cancel 5
3) n%5= 3 then  3n^2+3n-1 is divisible by 5 I 
4) n%5 = 4 then n+1 will help to cancel 5.
```

I am not able to come up with solution when case 1 or case 3 appears. Basically i dont want to compute n^2, can  anybody help me to arrive at solution

Comment: This is already pretty efficient. If $x$ is a nonnegative integer, you could write this as $\sum_{i = 1}^{x + n} i^4 - \sum_{i = 1}^x i^4$ and then use your closed form.

Comment: @Travis thanks, my programe was taking 1.3 ms, after using new formula it took 1.8ms..

Comment: @Travis - that's quite clever!

Comment: @hypergeometric Thank you.

Comment: @Travis My problem is solved, but i have one doubt. Let say I compute the above formula for all n=1 to $10^5$ and store it in some arrray dp[]. Now if i am given some value x<=$10^{10}$ and I am asked to compute  formula $\sum_{i=1}^{x}i^4$ and output result mod m <=$10^5$ how can i use existing table to calculate it.

Comment: @thetatheta By "above formula" do you just mean the quantity $\sum_{i = i}^n i^4$ for $n$ in the range?

Comment: @thetatheta Either way you might want to amend your original question to include the new question about computing sums modulo $m$; it's more interesting for one.

Comment: @Travis I got the answer. Just compute summation using the formula (n*(n+1)*(2n+1)*(3*n*n+ 3*n-1))mod (M*30) and divide the result by 30. It works thanks everybody

Answer (score 0):

Another approach, using binomial coefficients:
$$\begin{align}
\sum_{i=1}^{n}(x+i)^4&=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left[\binom{x+i+3}4+11\binom{x+i+2}4+11\binom{x+i+1}4+\binom{x+i}4\right]\\
&=\ \ \quad \binom{x+n+4}5+11\binom{x+n+3}5+11\binom{x+n+2}5+\binom{x+n+1}5\end{align}$$
which is nice and symmetrical and be easily evaluated.

If a factorised form is required, then substitute $y=x+n$ to get the rather untidy
$$\frac 1{30}y(y+1)(2y+1)(3y^2+3y-1)$$